# How to queue tasks for Worker (WorkerManager API)?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, workmanagers

I have a chain of requests

```
fun foo(){
....
WorkManager.getInstance(iC)
            .beginWith(downloadWorkRequest)
            .then(unzipWorkRequest)
            .then(deleteWorkRequest)
            .enqueue()
 .....
 }
```

This whole task (let's say) take 1 minute... Problem is that if I call this method a few times (for example 4 times) in one minute, so `WorkManager` really will start this task 4 times asynchronously.

I need that all this tasks will be executed synchronously (like queue).

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [unique work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/unique-work) in this case with a [`ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingWorkPolicy.html#APPEND)

```
fun foo(){
....
WorkManager.getInstance(iC)
           .beginUniqueWork(
               "my_unique_work_name",
               ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND,
               downloadWorkRequest)
           .then(unzipWorkRequest)
           .then(deleteWorkRequest)
           .enqueue()
 .....
 }
```

You can find an example of this in the [WorkManager codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager-kt/index.html).